# How could I make this animation occur when the element scrolls into view?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Title is self explanatory I just wish to be able to have the counting animation start when the element scrolls onto the page rather than animating when the page loads. I tried using  $(window).scroll(function ()  but couldn't get it to work using an if statement that would trigger the animation if the element was in between the top and bottom of the screen.

HTML:

```
<div class="sectiontitle">
    <h2>Projects statistics</h2>
    <span class="headerLine"></span>
</div>
<div id="projectFacts" class="sectionClass">
    <div class="fullWidth eight columns">
        <div class="projectFactsWrap ">
            <div class="item wow fadeInUpBig animated animated" data-number="12" style="visibility: visible;">
                <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>
                <p id="number1" class="number">12</p>
                <span></span>
                <p>Projects done</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item wow fadeInUpBig animated animated" data-number="55" style="visibility: visible;">
                <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>
                <p id="number2" class="number">55</p>
                <span></span>
                <p>Happy clients</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item wow fadeInUpBig animated animated" data-number="359" style="visibility: visible;">
                <i class="fa fa-coffee"></i>
                <p id="number3" class="number">359</p>
                <span></span>
                <p>Cups of coffee</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item wow fadeInUpBig animated animated" data-number="246" style="visibility: visible;">
                <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
                <p id="number4" class="number">246</p>
                <span></span>
                <p>Photos taken</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .sectionClass {
  padding: 20px 0px 50px 0px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.fullWidth {
  width: 100% !important;
  display: table;
  float: none;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.sectiontitle {
  background-position: center;
  margin: 30px 0 0px;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 20px;
}

.sectiontitle h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #222;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}


.headerLine {
  width: 160px;
  height: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #101F2E;
}


.projectFactsWrap{
    display: flex;
  margin-top: 30px;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


#projectFacts .fullWidth{
  padding: 50 !important;
}

.projectFactsWrap .item{
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.projectFactsWrap .item:nth-child(1){
  background: rgb(16, 31, 46);
}

.projectFactsWrap .item:nth-child(2){
  background: rgb(18, 34, 51);
}

.projectFactsWrap .item:nth-child(3){
  background: rgb(21, 38, 56);
}

.projectFactsWrap .item:nth-child(4){
  background: rgb(23, 44, 66);
}

.projectFactsWrap .item p.number{
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.projectFactsWrap .item p{
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}


.projectFactsWrap .item span{
  width: 60px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


.projectFactsWrap .item i{
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}


.projectFactsWrap .item:hover i, .projectFactsWrap .item:hover p{
  color: white;
}

.projectFactsWrap .item:hover span{
  background: white;
}

@media (max-width: 786px){
  .projectFactsWrap .item {
     flex: 0 0 50%;
  }
}

.trans{
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
  transform: translateX(0px);
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}
```

JQuery:

```
    <script>
$.fn.jQuerySimpleCounter = function( options ) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            start:  0,
            end:    100,
            easing: 'swing',
            duration: 400,
            complete: ''
        }, options );

        var thisElement = $(this);

        $({count: settings.start}).animate({count: settings.end}, {
            duration: settings.duration,
            easing: settings.easing,
            step: function() {
                var mathCount = Math.ceil(this.count);
                thisElement.text(mathCount);
            },
            complete: settings.complete
        });
    };


$('#number1').jQuerySimpleCounter({end: 12,duration: 3000});
$('#number2').jQuerySimpleCounter({end: 55,duration: 3000});
$('#number3').jQuerySimpleCounter({end: 359,duration: 2000});
$('#number4').jQuerySimpleCounter({end: 246,duration: 2500});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5qbw1p32/2/).

Add two conditions to avoid resetting animation every time `scroll` happen.

```
var animated = false;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll > 0 && !animated){
       $('#number1').jQuerySimpleCounter({end: 12,duration: 3000});
       $('#number2').jQuerySimpleCounter({end: 55,duration: 3000});
       $('#number3').jQuerySimpleCounter({end: 359,duration: 2000});
       $('#number4').jQuerySimpleCounter({end: 246,duration: 2500});
       animated = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the link [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Adeel91/pen/RVGBxj)

```
var executed = true;

$(window).scroll(function () {

    var $mainElement = $('#projectFacts'),
        windowScroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
        mainContainer = $mainElement.position().top;

    if (windowScroll > mainContainer && executed) {

        $('#number1').jQuerySimpleCounter({end: 12, duration: 3000});
        $('#number2').jQuerySimpleCounter({end: 55, duration: 3000});
        $('#number3').jQuerySimpleCounter({end: 359, duration: 2000});
        $('#number4').jQuerySimpleCounter({end: 246, duration: 2500});

        executed = false;

    }
});
```